How to get the injected URLs in Aspire service discovery
I currently have two projects:

API backend
Angular frontend with its own minimal backend.

The frontend project has 2 purposes:

Serve the angular application
provide one endpoint /settings which the Angular application calls to discover the APIs it can call.

The data returned by the /settings endpoint is read from one configuration section, which is bound to IOptions<ClientSettings>. The ClientSettings contains a list of APIs with their URLs.
I want to add Aspire to this solution.
How can I make sure the  URL coming from the Aspire service discovery is returned by my /settings endpoint?
My guess is that Aspire is injecting environment variables which are then somehow wired up when an HttpClient is being used. However I'm not using an HttpClient here, I just need to change what is returned by the endpoint.

When you add builder.AddServiceDefaults(); to your applications which implemented on ServiceDefaults project, it adds this code  builder.Services.AddServiceDiscovery().
Service discovery reads your urls from the "Services" section in the application settings.
So use this:

builder.Configuration.GetSection("Services").GetChildren();


you can read more about this here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/service-discovery?tabs=dotnet-cli
